# how to retreive only certain node in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Firebase rule based security not returning nodes that are readable

The realtime database consist of three nodes, productA, productB and **productC** at root level, I want to let only node A and B be read, but not at C level. Firebase simulator produce the correct result when at those levels, when I try code below it does not read the values

```
myDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/"); // does  not work

//myDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/productA"); // does work
...
myDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Iterable<DataSnapshot> snapshotIterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren();


                Iterator<DataSnapshot> iterator = snapshotIterator.iterator();

                while ((iterator.hasNext())) {

                    Object node= iterator.next();
                    String NodeKey = ((DataSnapshot) node).getKey();
                    Object NodeValue = ((DataSnapshot) node).getValue();
                    // dosomething
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                ItemList.add(databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

onDataChange should be fired for when root node is specified in getReference

Data is like [image].

Simulator returs [image] and
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firebase's [security rules don't filter your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters). They merely validate that the read operation is allowed. So if you attach a listener to the root, it checks if you have read permission on the root. Since you don't have read permission there, the entire read operation is rejected.

The emulator will give the same result if you also tell it to read the root (`/`).

Comment: thanks, how I can achieve same by modifying rule or DatabaseReference in a different manner

Comment: You'll have to be able to filter the data that you want to allow from the client-side, and then can use rules to validate the query. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query-based_rules

Answer (score 1):

When .read and .write rule permissions are evaluate to **true**, this would cascades to all of the rule’s children.

but falseness is not cascading

When .read and .write rule permissions are evaluate to **false**, this would **not** cascades to all of the rule’s children.

[source](https://androidnoobreboot.blogspot.com/p/firebase-2.html)